# Write a code golf problem in which Java wins

Tags: code-golf

Write a code golf task such that

1. The only input (if any) required by the task is text from standard input, and the only output required by the task is text to standard output.
2. There is exactly one correct output string of characters for every possible legal input as defined by the task.
3. Each possible legal input is less than 10000 characters long.
4. Each correct output is less than 10000 characters long.
5. **The shortest program** (that StackExchange users manage to write) **that successfully completes the task** for every input **is in Java.**

The task with the shortest associated Java program wins.

Comment: oh..... adding more constraints to Java again ;)

Comment: Receive XML as input, output a stacktrace.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## 48 characters

**Task:** Ignore any input. Always produce exactly the following output:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at M.<init>(M.java:1)
    at M.<clinit>(M.java:1)
```

**Solution:**

```
enum M{M;System x;{x.setErr(x.out);int y=1/0;}}
```

Save as `M.java`, compile with `javac M.java` and run with `java M`. It also produces an error message on standard error, but that doesn't violate any of the rules.

Comment: I had a similar idea.