# Quoted rational numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

[Quote notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quote_notation) is a way of expressing rational numbers based on the concept of [\$p\$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number), written in the form \$x'y\$.

The quote indicates that the number to it's left (\$x\$) is "repeated" infinitely to the left, then prefixed to the number on the right (\$y\$). For example \$3' = \: ...3333\$ and \$764'31 = \: ...76476431\$. We can then consider the geometric series:

$$\cdots + 10^{3k} + 10^{2k} + 10^{k} + 10^{0} = \frac 1 {1 - 10^k}$$

By setting \$k\$ to be equal to the number of digits of \$x\$, we can transform this "infinite" number into a value which converges:

$$\begin{align}
3' & = \: ...333
& 764'31 & = \: ...76476431 \\
   &
& & = 31 + 764'00 \\
   & = \cdots + 3\cdot10^3 + 3\cdot10^2 + 3\cdot10^1 + 3\cdot10^0
& & = 31 + 100 \times 764'\\
   & = 3(\cdots + 10^3 + 10^2 + 10^1 + 10^0)
& & = 31 + 100 \times 764(\cdots + 10^9 + 10^6 + 10^3 + 10^0)\\
   & = 3\left( \frac 1 {1 - 10} \right) 
& & = 31 + 76400\left( \frac 1 {1 - 10^3} \right) \\
   & = \frac {3} {-9}
& & = 31 - \frac {76400} {999}\\
   & = - \frac 1 3
& & = - \frac {45431} {999}
\end{align}$$

Note that \$9'0 \ne 9'\$ as the first equals \$-10\$ and the second \$-1\$. Additionally, note that leading zeros on \$y\$ do affect the output: \$81'09 = -\frac {801} {11} \ne \frac {9} {11} = 81'9\$ Therefore, a value after the \$'\$ (\$y\$) may be omitted in the input.

You are to take, in any reasonable format, up to 2 non-negative integers \$x\$ and \$y\$, and output the fraction \$\frac a b\$ represented by \$x'y\$. Reasonable formats include:

- A string, delimited by a non-digit character, such as `'`, e.g. `9'` or `9'0`. The string will always begin with a digit; if there is no \$x\$ value, it will be a \$0\$ (e.g. `0'3`)
- A list of either 1 or 2 non-negative integers, represented as strings or lists of digits. If there is only 1, it represents \$x'\$. 2 integers represent \$x'y\$.
- A list of 2 elements. The last element may be either a non-negative integer (as a string or digit list), or a consistent value that is not a non-negative integer (e.g. `null` or `None` or `-1` etc.) that indicates that there is no \$y\$ value. The first value will always be a non-negative integer.

This is not an exhaustive list, if you have another method, feel free to ask.

You may output the two integers \$a\$ and \$b\$ instead of the fraction \$\frac a b\$. The fraction must be exact, and fully simplified (i.e. \$a\$ and \$b\$ are coprime). If \$b\$ is 1, outputting just \$a\$ is acceptable. For negative outputs, if outputting \$a\$ and \$b\$ separately, either may have the negative sign, but not both.

You may input and output in any [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

---

Modified from the linked Wikipedia page:

> Let \$x\$ and \$y\$ be sequences of digits, as in \$x'y\$
>
> Let \$z\$ be the digit \$1\$ followed by a sequence of zeros of the same length as \$y\$.
>
> Let \$w\$ be a sequence of \$9\$s of the same length as \$x\$.
>
> Then the number represented by \$x'y\$ is given by \$y-\frac{xz}w\$

### Test cases

```
x'y    = a / b
31'491 = 17609 / 99
844'80 = -4480 / 999
4'128  = -2848 / 9
247'0  = -2470 / 999
0'716  = 716 / 1
592'   = -16 / 27
3'45   = 35 / 3
9'7    = -3 / 1
9'     = -1 / 1
3'0    = -10 / 3
764'31 = -45431 / 999
81'09  = -801 / 11
81'9   = 9 / 11
123456' = -41152 / 333333
```

Comment: Apologies for any potential inaccuracies with the actual mathematics - I'm not especially familiar with \$p\$-adic numbers, or this notation. If any doubt arises from such inaccuracies, what's in the challenge is "correct", at least for answers

Comment: Leading zeros are significant in both numbers, right? e.g. `081'09 = 33/37`

Comment: @Neil Leading zeros are significant for \$y\$, but not for \$x\$, as they can be normalised out. You can assume that \$x\$ will never have leading zeros

Comment: Ah, so `081'10` would be written `810'8110 = 70/37`?

Comment: Or actually `108'110`, I guess.

Comment: @Neil Yes, as you can "roll" the infinite side into the right to get the same value

Comment: But instead of quote notation, i have learned dot notation, which adds dots on the top of numbers, i was thinking of posting challenge before you.... anyways nice idea

Comment: @Wasif Sorry for sniping you, I just found out about this notation in the past couple of days :)

Comment: Regarding input method 2, may I take an empty array for \$y\$ when the input is in the form of \$x'\$ (instead of omitting the input entirely)?

Comment: @Bubbler Yeah, that's perfectly reasonable, go ahead

Comment: Can we take input formatted like e.g. `[[3, 1], 4, 9, 1]`?

Comment: @att I'm going to say no, as it isn't clear enough how the two numbers are separated

Comment: Can't leading zeros be normalized out for y as well? `12'034 = 12'12034 = 21'2034` and `012'034 = 201'2034`

Comment: @tjjfvi Yeah, I suppose they can. However, for the sake of convenience, I'm going to leave the rules as they are

Answer (score 14):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

```
(%-.)~/@(10^#&>)#.10#.&>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WgrqNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NVR19TTr9B00DA3ilNXsNJX1DA2U9dTsYv9r/k9TsKhQMKxQsFYwqFCwrOBC8MEcS7CMigGIbQxRBWSZVyiYVSiYgPjGINUA)

Takes a boxed 2-item vector containing the digit vectors of \$x\$ and \$y\$, and returns a rational number. The digits must be given in extended precision. \$y\$ may be an empty vector. I guess it's pretty well golfed when Jelly is at 20 bytes :)

#### How it works

Uses the formula at the end of the challenge. If we define \$\#x\$ as the number of digits of \$x\$,

$$
z = 10^{\#y}, \quad w=10^{\#x}-1, \quad x'y = -\frac{z}{w}x+y,
$$

and observe that the result is the same as the 2-vector \$[x,y]\$ evaluated in base \$-\frac{z}{w}\$.

```
(%-.)~/@(10^#&>)#.10#.&>]    NB. Monadic train; input = (digits of x;digits of y)
                  10#.&>]    NB. Evaluate each in base 10 to get [x,y]
                #.           NB. Evaluate in base...
        (10^#&>)    NB. 10 raised to the power of length of each; [10^#x, 10^#y]
(%-.)~/@            NB. (10^#y) / (1 - 10^#x) = -z/w
```

---

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 23 bytes

```
(%-.)~&(10x^#)#.,&{.&".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NCoJAEIDvPsWg5CjoMqOj7gqegk6deoA8hBJdAk9B0Ktvu2tJhxYGdr5v/m42VjjD0ANCAQS9i1LB/nQ82GxXqvyVZkyPc5InqkifKo2VzaNoulzvgDUjzIBiGFfCXUtmMQYG@GNHEU3Oeo1aJGhNX1tJt1n3D3aT7KkJ7IM6bj2jwFyyLWFuqqUOzxdwVUvT/naOmnjhMFGvN5JB@wY)

Modification of [Jonah's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222886/78410) to use the same base trick. This one is a dyadic function accepting plain strings as its two args. One caveat is that eval(`".`) of an empty string is an empty vector, so we need to make it a 0 explicitly using `{.`.

Comment: That's a very clever approach, which I think would heavily outgolf the existing Jelly answer!

Comment: "and observe that the result is the same as the 2-vector [,] evaluated in base..." Very nice!

Answer (score 10):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```
d[#/d[0#-9]]~d~#2&
d=Fold[9#+##&]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY47C4MwFIV3f0XggktvqSa@MlicOrd0DA5ilArVQrFTSP66zcPB7ZyPc889c7e@hrlbp77bxnqTAi5SJHDmbWukARpHsr593lJwOAHE7fb4TcPa3L/Tsgo4X8emgTY2z75bjIqUYkhSjSpDwp3SaFmFxPpMI3EyCdDbFAlFUgVCfax0fM8kTpe2B0kRSO57qeMBMCftWR4s9xcHfUjtpbav2New48TUZ2x/IGEa85ty99@XRXr7Aw)

Input two lists of digits.

`Fold[9#+##&]` is longer than `FromDigits`, but has more flexibility with its input.

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal v2.6.0pre1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.6.0pre1), <s>15</s> 11 bytes

```
vL↵‡⌐/R?⌊$β
```

Haha rationals go brrr. Obligatory port of Jelly, M and Bubbler.

### Explained

```
vL↵‡⌐/R?⌊$β  # Full program, takes ["x", "y"]
vL           # vectorise length over each
  ↵          # and raise 10 to the power of each
   ‡⌐/       # lambda x, y: x / 1 - y
      R      # reduce the above list by that
       ?⌊    # cast each string in input to it
         $β  # and convert to the result of reducing the lambda
```

### History

I spent roughly an hour on this, trying to arrange it to work properly. Took me a few re-reads of the specs, but I got there in the end.

Input taken as:

```
y
x
```

where `y` and `x` are strings (done by surrounding them with `""`s), and if `y` isn't provided, `[]` is used.

### Explained

```
L↵⁰I*⁰L↵‹/¹I$-ƒ
L↵               # 10 ** length(y)
  ⁰I             # int(x)
    *            # ↑ * ↑↑ (we'll call this W)
     ⁰L↵         # 10 ** length(x)
        ‹        # ↑ - 1
         /       #  W / ↑
          ¹I     # int(y) # on an empty list, this will return 0
            $-   # ↑↑ - ↑
              ƒ  # fractionify(↑) # this built-in has been around for a long time before this challenge --> it turns a decimal into the most simple fraction
```

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>118</s> <s>116</s> <s>108</s> <s>103</s> <s>98</s> 92 bytes

```r
function(x,y,`+`=nchar,B=10^+x-1,A=el(max(y,0):0)*B-x*10^+y,q=1:x)c(A,B)/max(q[!A%%q&!B%%q])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1RC4IwEMDxdz@FGqtNJ92VpCfswX2NKCZSFJShFMxPvzZ9OY7f/eEmZ9iOGeXuv6H/Pj8Dt3KWJjdq6B/dJLVCuOa2QNmq24u/O8tnCaIBkenCZuE4y1FhY0XPW6nFPiTjOWkZG7eJ9vMi3BH9k7QkTOMNViegeB8TRYeyCg5eC7/DohTVSw0UuAb0ihhRsDRCxHVZo9DQErg/)

Takes first input as integer and second as string (empty if no \$y\$).

GCD implementation borrowed from here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48845/55372

*-8 bytes thanks to [@Kirill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l) & [@Dominic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen);

-5 and another -6 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

Comment: A quick saving: replace `ifelse` with `"if"`

Comment: I think this can get down to [108 bytes](https://tio.run/##Hc3RCoIwFAbge5/CFqtNZ@6UpIt2oa8RxdSShFLUBPXl1@bN4ef7fzi9VniPldTV2JS/um3IxGamfCWb8p33LJPAH/4UAEulqitFlmvgzywfDs92LD4vMlPGqZcFk2eGC@skXPJiICmlJUlZRsNvPpHutkkx7nabzNw71ScwT1EkALnbAOIzF27oCuEco9gW3LLJfFXhJOucC8sJB6MAjrCGHIC1RPoP)... which frustratingly beats [my own attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222935/95126)...

Comment: `el(y:0)` is a _very_ clever workaround for `strtoi` or `as.double`. I think `q=1:B` should work, since \$x\leq B\$ and thus \$GCD(x,y)\leq \min(x,y)\leq x\leq B\$

Comment: @Giuseppe, the `el` trick is from [R tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024/tips-for-golfing-in-r#comment412911_12837). Thanks for the `q` tip - I'm lost in the math here already :)

Comment: @pajonk the math's pretty simple: the GCD of two numbers is always less than or equal to them, so I just tried to find a number you'd already defined that was bigger than `x`. That being said, it's more memory efficient to just use `x` rather than `B`, since `q=1:x` would also work.

Comment: I also got a little inspiration from your `el(y:0)` to get down to [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc1RC4IwEMDxdz@FGqtNJ92VpCfswX2NKCZSFJShFMxPvzZ9OY7f/eEmZ9iOGeXuv6H/Pj8Dt3KWJjdq6B/dJLVCuOa2QNmq24u/O8tnCaIBkenCZuE4y1FhY0XPW6nFPiTjOWkZG7eJ9vMi3BH9k7QkTOMNViegeB8TRYeyCg5eC7/DohTVSw0UuAb0ihhRsDRCxHVZo9DQErg/)

Comment: @Giuseppe - the ```max(```-empty string-```,0)``` trick is really clever!

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>114</s> <s>110</s> <s>109</s> <s>107</s> 104 bytes

*Edit: -4 and then -2 more bytes thanks to Giuseppe's comments on pajonk's answer, and then -3 bytes after copying a trick from Robin Ryder's answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223168/95126)*

```r
function(s,z=10^nchar(s)-1:0,n=scan(t=pmax(s,0)),a=c(diff(n*z[2:1]),z[1]),c=1:z)a/max(c[!a%%c&!a[2]%%c])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdJha4QgGAfw9/sUHuOWjo7zUUsN/CTRhniLHWzeVh2MvnzTGK0Nu16IwY9//3zsps/rZXg5PXd2OF@8fTNTe/Uu7nGfjwbok3evtsM9OUBFc296Zz0ezMe7/QqCEpJb4/Dp3LbYP441q6Ah@VjH1RmoRmKPkbp6Z/d797CzNWvCpiH/v4wdzjhkeSY0ZIgQdI8MAllSjY5I67sEV0IEr@jCD0IoOvOkjxqYytDimRIq@pRmQgZP11rIG@k0aAnlrw8vQUPKFpoFHeiSPVsmU5jHQylWmBfB8hTVsUOUSy7fqqB/Cqwq3KL0TyrQLcvTNtlWlnEiHFbzKwSH7SNW8X5QvRqJonPrZBVgXBRl/M0lHqBgsc38TN8)

Input is a vector of two strings representing `x` and `y`.

I tried to answer this without peeking at the other [R](https://www.r-project.org/) answers, but now I realise that [pajonk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222898/95126) is <s>probably</s> golfier...  Bah!

Comment: Having a choice of input format makes golfing harder, because you have to think about which is going to be golfiest!

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>(G=(a,b)=>b?G(b,a%b):[x/a,z/a])(z=-1+x-~x,x-=y+x-(x+y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/JTsMwEIbvfgoLCY2tZnPsLKZyOKE@AMdSqU4XSJUmURqhtAhePdgOPeDDLJ/@f2Z80p/6suurbvCbdn@YjmoaVXFVBVkpor2SqqJ8XpHS048lfVqPofZuod5QclM@W4z@z@iNvrqaioyLK6XTgBXeIs5ASGZKlqWRxCGWEuVCQB4Z5gthsmUSCWBxji2Mc5FbiGKRQTQjkd11EWQstdCmEDOUyBiwUzkQZ4iDSBzhiQEcScjwrODOIa1@drie2y1zHzlDlgrgzB2YCM7@NucMzA8szSNnZBZJ55Rzz2IukhSck7EkttPcQ9tg6KszocGlq6uBwFsDNDjrjtRYFbi@YwV0HW3@ax/ggdIlGoJj27/o3cds@UIY79rm0taHoG7fSR2c2qpx4qDT@9dB9wNhEfUwqAI8fCS1mUxNZBs6a8GcB3b0N11Ovw)

Take input as two strings, output an array with two numbers.

JavaScript use `+` for both number plus and string concatenation. When any operand is string, it works as string concatenation.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>39 32 30</sup> 27 bytes

```
{.@".@]-".@[*(%<:)~&(10x^#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwDEDv@4qgaDZxJdm6rR0OhoIn8eBVdAdxiBdhJ0Hw12vb6VAwkNC8l7S9mpHAFqoSEOZAUNqMBax2m7V5iHok6kNsy34WThZl9JyGTPfjODJRsF0K@JkIgvPpcgNMGaEFlJqxJ1zkpDutoYI/tpFSkbVOo5LSa0Ufm8hisPbs7SDZUe3ZGxWcO0ae2WZ4hDlLutSHG@AklVn@vdko4o79jar/I2k0Lw)

<sup>-5 thanks to Bubbler.  Also go upvote [his j answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222891/15469), which is more creative and has delightful application of base `#.`</sup>

The wikipedia formula translated into J.  The only part that might be of some interest is the calculation of `z/w`:

- `(%&x:<:)~&(10^#)`

  - `&(1>.10^#)` Convert each string input by raising 10 to the power of its length `10^#` (which will be 1 when length is 0).
  - `(%&x:<:)~` Next swap the argument order `~` and subtract 1 `<:` from the new right arg, to get a number whose digits are all nines.  Divide the left argument by that `%`.

Comment: You can remove explicit `x:` call by making the values extended early, e.g. by using `10x^`.

Comment: Thanks @Bubbler.  I'm racking my brain for a way to further golf this part `{.@".@]-".@[`, but I'm fried and if there is one I don't see it.

Comment: `1>.` is not needed, as `x` part is never empty. After some rearrangement (some of which is also used in my code), [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY7BCoJAEEDvfsWg5GjosKOr7gpCFHSKDl2jPEQSXQJPgdCvb@ta0qGFWWbe252Zu/EJO2hqQEhAQG0jJdgcdlsTLVKKX2HE4nkO4oCScKDQJxN7@zXBQCufVqfUXsel510vtwdgzggdoNSME@GqFLrXGhr4Y1splbB21KikdFqJr81kNVubOztLHql27IMqLkcmHLPFPIS5yPrcnfEBZ7ksyt@frRLcs@uoph2FRvMG) solution seems to work.

Comment: I fixed the superfluous max, but I think you should take the 23 byte solution for your answer, since you deserve all the fruits of the base trick.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>80</s>  76 bytes

Expects `(x)(y)` as strings (`y` may be an empty string) and returns `[numerator, denominator]`.

```javascript
x=>y=>(G=(a,b)=>b?G(b,a%b):[p/a,q/a])(q=1-10**x.length,p=y*q+x*10**y.length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/LboMwEEX3fMUoUmWbEMDYvFqZrtp@QJZJVDkJJFSUdytQ1W@nxlAvxqOjc8fjD/ktu0ub1/2urK7plIlpEMkoEvwmsLTORCTn5zd8tuTDmTweakdajSNPBDeC7qhrmoNdpOWtv1u1GM1mO5gzHFdIpjZtvvI2xSjrELHbVF5f8yLdj@UFu8Tuq33f5uUNE7uri7zH6FgqLavaF3m54w5EAj8GQJH2cIB3CwYLRjiBgM7@lL1SHHy8bglS1SQOeVLupSq7qkjtorrhAbawQRtVx7k79iLZWJDhgeCRKPuXTIwiHlNQI2kYuDE4EMdGxDmK3BnuOFfNDGODI@pFoKkX8WimhsdD5K6Mh/@mi0IaaDrfDlDDjz0Ei6eJFxoMcX9BzFeEGTEKYXWYDsU6soQ0YPqtBbg6EwYcMbps6nNG1wUiitRfNI5cnaUG9Rj3A6RVSn1vzuvzBw)

#### Commented

```javascript
x =>                       // outer function taking x
y =>                       // inner function taking y
  ( G = (a, b) =>          // G is a helper function which takes 2 integers,
      b ? G(b, a % b)      // computes their GCD a
        : [ p / a, q / a ] // and eventually returns [ p / a, q / a ]
  )(                       // we invoke G with (q, p) defined as follows:
    q =                    //   q =
      1 -                  //   1 - 10 ** len(x)
      10 ** x.length,      //
    p =                    //   p =
      y * q +              //   y * q + x * 10 ** len(y)
      x * 10 ** y.length   //
  )                        //
```

Comment: TBH I don't see any significant reason to disallow it (and doing so seems kinda unfair), so I'll allow having the negative sign on either, inconsistently, so long as it is only one one

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 58 bytes

```hs
x#y=f y-f x*0!y/1!x
c!s=10^length s-c
f x=read$'0':x++"%1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY9Pc8IgEMXvfAqMdtBqDATyh4701ltPvVo7EkXNFImTMNPk06dAWi47@9v3dh832X0rrcfxNOsEwV9amau9wS4@gQvsRavkeYEweunX6@iJRKCfD@ICh9gNn/FsSMisH@@yNlDAcwMg3JuN3FSHXfzTtOdue6m1Ve3yaBr7ptX9GIkkWu0Wr1dl32ujnEEru@w3w0p0D2mWiUCfCK3MNNhLt6s6CNt8SFs3RuqtD@T8e3/EiR5tbexCyqSqhOjnVtYaDo77SCMliHHikpEixxwmkHNQMoZK7FjMmKueccAQSUvoYVqy0kOQsgLhCbHiX4dRQXIPfUkgARlPEQyqANICUMSyQGjmAAUcFXBS0ODgXj85Qk/9lanHwVDkDFESAmaMkr/LJUHuB56WOBgJICllWY6CkpAs9e7wfgE)

The relevant function is `(#)`, which takes `x` and `y` as strings, with `y` possibly empty. Returns a `Rational`.

**DISCLAIMER:** the compiler is unable to correctly deduce the type of `(#)`, unless it is specified by some other part of the program, either explicitly (i.e. `::Rational`) or implicitly (i.e. by using the return value as if it were a `Rational`). Based on [this Meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12747/82619) I believe this should be allowed, but since I'm quite inexperienced I'm not sure. If that's not the case, then the best I can do is:

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
x#y=f y-f x*0!y/1!x
c!s=10^length s-c
f x=toRational.read$'0':x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/LbsMgEEX3fAV5SJNUcQwGP6hCd9111W2aKjghiVUHRzZS7a93AbebshnNmXvnDjfVfem6Hsd@McgLHqIL7p/IbIjprEenWScp@ay1udob7qITclNpm3dlq8aoettqdV4Cged@vKvKYInPDcJ4bzZqUx520XfTnrvtpaqtbldH09jXWt@PcxnP17vly1Xbt8poZ6i1XfWbYS27hzKrWMIHwNpMg71yu8rD/1jn3/sQJ3q0lbFLpeKylLJfWFXVeHDcnzQyClxQdxnNMyJwjIVABedQEMcizl31TCAONCmwh0nBCw9RwnMgE@L5n45ATjMPfYkxRalIAAdVAEmOGPA0EJY6wJCAHE8KFhzC6ydH6JlPmXoSDHnGgdFwYMoZ/U0uKLgfeFqQYKSIJoynGQQlpWni3eH9AA)

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails for the recently added `81'09` test case (it calculates `81'9` instead). Additionally, `Rational` types are perfectly fine IMO for input

Comment: My bad, I did not realize `y` could have leading zeros. I'll delete this answer for now, since I don't have time to change it at the moment. Thanks for the clarification about `Rational`s.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) `+ MASS`, <s>99</s> 91 bytes

```r
function(x,y,`[`=gsub)MASS::fractions(eval(parse(t=paste0(y,"-",x,"."[0,y],"/","."[9,x]))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdBNboMwEAXgfU9huRsjmWbGP9iOyqIH6CrLKFJoBVWlKo2AVHB66jExrVfwPs1jTL907LlkS3e7vI@f3xcxyVmej@f6Y7i9Fa8vh8N@3/VNskG0P82XuDb90IqxvjbD2IKYJS@5nCR/4keQ80nyHU8vQU6nIp6lE1xjzExAXjyymqGrILAdC@EhmjcmoofVSmM8JEtIhMqTESpvPCGRMi4ibGTcvzmI5LC6Y3yKhAQ2qEgpp6kEypFoWtFm0TaCpjxQ1RrThM5NYetZm3Kut63WHHKRq@g2GvNFrdH4t7GnXwQhX8dDKkyNqLSx1f1zNIloFbWms/wC)

Takes input as two strings (`y` possibly empty), outputs a rational fraction or an integer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly (fork)](https://github.com/https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/jellylanguage), 11 bytes

```
ḌḅẈ⁵*C÷@¥/Ʋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4biM4biF4bqI4oG1KkPDt0DCpS/Gsv///1s4LDFdLFswLDld), or rather, don't

As of last week, my fork now includes symbolic math support! Unfortunately, [M](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222926/66833) (Jelly's version with symbolic math) only implements this in the `İ` atom, not in the `÷` division atom. My fork does both.

Again, implements [Bubbler's strategy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222891/66833) to evaluate \$[x, y]\$ in base \$-\frac z w\$.

### How it works

```
ḌḅẈ⁵*C÷@¥/Ʋ - Main link. Takes [x, y] as lists of digits on the left
Ḍ           - Convert [x, y] to integers
          Ʋ - Do the following to [x, y]:
  Ẉ         -   Lengths of each
   ⁵*       -   Raise 10 to the power of each length
        ¥/  -   Reduce by the following:
     C      -     Complement; 1 - a
      ÷@    -     Divide b by that; b / (1 - a)
```

Comment: actual symbolic math? or just rationals

Comment: @ASCII-only Whatever `sympy` supports

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
9ṁḌ+Ø.µ×³ḌU¤_/,Ḣ:g/$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/y4c7Ghzt6tA/P0Du09fD0Q5uBnNBDS@L1dR7uWGSVrq/y////aGMdw1idaBMdSyANAA)

Seems very bad ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>96</s> 92 bytes

```
(.+)'(.*)
$($($.1*9)*$2*)-$($1$.2*0)*_/$($.1*9)*
+`_-_
-
-/
/
(_+)(\1)*/(\1)*$
$.(_$#2*)/$#3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtLDsIwEEP3vkYHzafKZ9JCmxNwCaSUBQs2LBD3DxELZNl6luX34/N83b2f5Hp0ibOyRFOQDEW3qkbFNIzmFItltZb@E@ajhYaAkJAgbVa5uVr6JYGiNJrGPdG09L6ylx1l3Tgj8@YXnGthLLyeUXkbHpyxO@f6BQ) Link includes faster test cases. Explanation:

```
(.+)'(.*)
$($($.1*9)*$2*)-$($1$.2*0)*_/$($.1*9)*
```

Write out `yw-xz/w`. (Edit: I don't actually multiply `x` by `z`, I just suffix the appropriate number of `0`s to it, which saves on a `1` amongst other things.)

```
+`_-_
-
-/
/
```

Perform the subtraction, slowly.

```
(_+)(\1)*/(\1)*$
$.(_$#2*)/$#3
```

Slowly divide by the GCD and convert to decimal.

Just for completeness, optimising for speed results in code that readily dispatches all of the test cases. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYs7csMwDET7vYaRgKCGIkFCH1YqcwmNpRQp3KTw5Gw@gC@m0Co8GOws9i3uP3@33289PtzXfri@E3a9F5Br06uv4il7Ce1S6rNP4rf4Rrjvqwa3eYmIuLqtk7AqAq5hAfHzQZ/o9jOPq/pXEZQjKeJyhsvz4cIiblXp4qmN06VEuthxFGWritmM5wRjzTOyTZyQeNIRQ82Mwjag8tS2@YRpNC7tSTlVaC42jPwP)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 70 bytes

Not great, but I felt like submitting it anyway

```apl
{⍺←⍬⋄{⍵÷⊃⌽⊃∩⍥(⍸0=⊢|⍨⍳)/|⍵}((W×⍎'0',⍺)-(⍎⍵)×⍎'1','0'\⍨⍴,⍺),W←⍎'9'\⍨⍴,⍵}
```

Not sure why, but my code to handle single arguments works in TryAPL.org but not in tio.run

Also, because of how APL handles default arguments, I had to swap the order on input...like I said, not the best solution :|

```apl
⍺←⍬⋄ ⍝ assign Empty Set to the default value for the left argument (Y from the problem statement)
 ⍵÷⊃⌽ ⍝ divide the 2-tuple (a and b from the problem statement) by their gcd
  ⊃ ⍝ pick (removes one layer of nesting)
   ∩ ⍝ intersection
    ⍥ ⍝ function composition operator (Over)
     (⍸0=⊢|⍨⍳)/ ⍝ fold/reduce by finding divisors
      |⍵ ⍝ absolute value of 2-tuple (a and b from the problem statement)
       W×⍎'0',⍺ ⍝ W (from problem statement) times the integer representation of the left argument (Y from the problem statement) or zero if alpha is the empty set
        -(⍎⍵) ⍝ subtract the integer representation of the right argument (X from the problem statement)
         ×⍎ ⍝ decode then multiply
          '1', ⍝ concatenate the character 1
           '0'\⍨⍴ ⍝ expand the character 0 by the number of characters in Y
             ,⍺ ⍝ ravel Y (effectively making single characters into singleton arrays)
              , ⍝ concatenate
                W←⍎'9'\⍨⍴ ⍝ assign the integer representation of the expansion of the character 9 by the number of characters in X
                 ,⍵ ⍝ ravel X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R24TqR727gNSj3jWPuluAnK2Htz/qan7UsxdEdqx81LtU41HvDgPbR12Lah71rnjUu1lTH8jYWquhEX54@qPePnUDdR2gGZq6QHV9QAlNiKihug5QJgasZQtYgU442J4@dUsk4a21//@rm1gaqiukKagbG6pzqVsYgNkWJiZAjqGRBZgHYkPEjUzMgWxzQzMwzwDINjGFaAYJg1mWcMUgMWOI2eZmYDMsIYaDLEIwgZSppRGYtgSThkbGJqZm6gA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 55 bytes

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ'«≔ζη≔ιζ»≔Ｉ⭆η⁹δ≔⁻×ＩζδＩ⁺η⭆ζ⁰ε⊞υε⊞υδＷ﹪εδ«≔δε≔ιδ»⪫÷υ↔δ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/NqsIwEIXX@hShGycQ0btTXMl1o1Ao6Av0mmgGcpPSJAoVnz1OWvFnl5M555szR123R1eblE6uZbBvDAbY2iaGfWjRnoELVkwKzm7j0dp7PFvoBNN89ZIoWEfyPn7q39oHGMJl3YAWbMkJIsnzdJRoo4cD/is/uLt@LlgvKkNDSr0RtHDOeYYoglTRa4jf7wy/ajSKQelkNA5U/vxsLYfER2vZt65oS4CdQ0tnhw1eUKqMXP95Z2JQIPPiYlZwvkpp8TOZL9P0Yh4) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ'«≔ζη≔ιζ»
```

Split the input string on `'` and save the parts into separate variables.

```
≔Ｉ⭆η⁹δ
```

Change the digits of the first part to `9`s and save the result as an integer.

```
≔⁻×ＩζδＩ⁺η⭆ζ⁰ε
```

Multiply that by the second part as an integer, then change the digits of the second part to `0`s, append that to the first part, and subtract the integer value.

```
⊞υε⊞υδ
```

Save the fraction to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｗ﹪εδ«≔δε≔ιδ»
```

Find the GCD.

```
⪫÷υ↔δ/
```

Reduce the fraction to its lowest terms and output it with a `/` separator.

Answer (score 3):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 92 bytes

```clj
#(let[b biginteger p(fn[x](.pow(b 10)(count x)))](-(b(or %2 0))(/(*(b %)(p %2))(dec(p %)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZFNboMwEIX3PsWIKPK4UhL/AXarngSxgZiICgEFR01Pn9qY1Kvx5/fGTzPtMH3dF/fEq@ugex5wcL5qoOlv/ejdzS0wYzdWjxrP8/SDDQjOsJ3uo4cHY6zGEzY4LXCUwBnDC74FzZHhHEi4X10bSxbPkxG8Tqv7hsq71UNFMiWotiL7gE8QZcEtXMBakhmtqeEbPmlt@IYD11RIE3Dk0mgTOcmkLil/UV3@qzktRZF4KAIVJMutpBFF7cZkGVJQne9Q5YEpkllabiTqVLLaZEzWhFT6NyGenGWhqRJ79lwr8YpjBOV2j2n41iG0EFLpvKC7XohcxjbbITW8x21UD/itAdu0qfPql368XdZ56D1sgzxkNGN1TXAOL34YATsInjjyPw)

Relies on the formula from Wikipedia. Takes input as two strings (`nil` when there is no `y`), outputs a rational fraction, or a bigint when denominator is 1.

Answer (score 3):

## [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 13 bytes

```
Cİ×
L€⁵*ç/ḅ@Ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9t//9DxLDDlwpM4oKs4oG1KsOnL@G4hUDhuIz///9bOCwxXSxbMCw5XQ)

Implements [Bubbler's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222891/66833)

### How it works

```
Cİ× - Helper link. Takes a on the left and b on the right
C   - Yield 1-a
 İ  - Inverse; Yield 1 / (1-a)
  × - Times; Yield b / (1-a)

L€⁵*ç/ḅ@Ḍ - Main link. Takes [x, y] as lists of digits
L€        - Length of each
  ⁵*      - Raise 10 to the power of the lengths
    ç/    - Run the helper link with the powers of 10 as a and b
        Ḍ - Convert [x, y] into integers
      ḅ@  - Evaluate [x, y] as base b / (1-a)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-apl`, 99 bytes

```perl
($w,$z)=map s/./9/gr,@F;@e=($F[1]*$w-$F[0]*($z+1),$w);$w--while grep$_%$w,@e;$_=join"/",map$_/$w,@e
```

Takes two space separated strings from `stdin`, outputs a fraction.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczdCsIgGIDhW5HxBbo0k/4IETzaTcSQHXwsw6a4QNjFZ9LZy3PwJszhUiuFwmFj5j0lssqDvMs5cztoi4bC8FBjD0W0OI49hW2vGIfCdDNRnj4gmTMmcLt2sajBmVf0Syc73n7g5J9rvV3P5KS@MX18XNYqphR@)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÂI‚JÆ-нID®ì+н>‚D¿÷
```

Despite 05AB1E's name (when `05AB1E` converted to hexadecimal is interpret as base64 it spells `Base`), it can't do base conversion from decimal values, so [*@Bubbler*'s approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222891/52210) won't work for it.
Instead, this is a port of [*@tsh*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222951/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!

This uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because the GCD builtin `¿` will always result in a positive integer in the new version of 05AB1E (the `D¿÷` should be `Ð.±s¿*ß÷` as workaround in that case).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cJPno4ZZXofbdC/s9XQ5tO7wGu0Le@2AQi6H9h/e/v9/tLGhjomlYSwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCaH/DzdFPGqY5XW4TffC3giXQ@sOr9G@sNcOKORyaP/h7f91/kdHGxvqmFgaxupEW5iY6FgYABkmOoZGFkDayMRcB8Q30DE3NAPSppZGOkpKQIaxjokpkLLUMQeTUDGQUnMzEx1jsGGGOkoGlkoQliWQMjQyNjE1A6mNBQA).

**Explanation:**

Uses the formula:

$$(x,y) = [x-(y\mathbin\Vert x-x\mathbin\Vert y), \text{-1}\mathbin\Vert x + x + 1]$$

integer-divided by their \$\gcd\$ afterwards; where \$\mathbin\Vert\$ is concatenation, taking precedence over the other operators.

```python
Â        # Reverse the (implicit) input-pair (without popping)
 I‚      # Pair it with the input-pair
   J     # Join both inner pairs together
    Æ    # Reduce this pair by subtracting
     -   # Subtract this integer from both values of the input-pair
      н  # Pop and only keep the first one
ID       # Push the input-pair twice again
  ®ì     # Prepend both integers in the top pair with "-1"
    +    # Add both to the input-pair at the same positions
     н   # Pop and only keep the first one
      >  # Increase it by 1
‚        # Pair the two values together
 D       # Duplicate this pair
  ¿      # Get the GCD (Greatest Common Divisor)
   ÷     # Integer-divide the values in the pair by this GCD
         # (after which the pair is output implicitly as result)
```